# Putting restrictions on if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, console-application

This is a very basic question but how do i only allow numberic values in my if statement?
For example if user inputs string as an id it should give an error saying only numeric value allowed.

```
Console.Write("Please enter your ID: ");
int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if () // what should I write here?
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only Numeric value are allowed.");
}else{
Console.WriteLine("My ID is {0}", id);}
```

Comment: can you use the `char.IsDigit` function perhaps ..? read up on it and try it..

Comment: @BlueTrin yes, I'd say so too

Comment: you could just not have the if sentence at all.
Int32.Parse will throw an exception if the string is not a valid number.. so `try{ int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  Console.WriteLine("My ID is {0}", id);} }catch{ Console.WriteLine("Only Numeric value are allowed."); }` is an option..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.Write("Please enter your ID: ");
int id;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id)) // what should I write here?
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only Numeric value are allowed.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("My ID is {0}", id);
}
```

`TryParse` group of methods will not raise an exception if parsing is failed, instead they returns a `bool` indicating success or failure.

Comment: It's giving an error saying "the best overloaded method have some invalid argument". :/

Comment: @samjohal, my bad, it should have been `Console.ReadLine`, instead of `Console.Read`

Answer (score 3):

You should do the parse in the `if` using [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int id;

if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out id))
{
    // it's an integer!
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression such as:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("[0-9]") == false)
```

Comment: Not the preferred approach, since you need to parse it twice. `int.TryParse` does it all for you.